# Establishing continuity for a complex variable function

Tags: complex-numbers, continuity

In the real numbers, if one is to complete continuity of a function such as:
${x^4-1\over x-1}$ The solution can be obtained as follows:
${(x^3+x^2+x+1)(x-1) \over x-1}$ from which we can conlude, that to maintain continuity, we must make $f(x) = 4$  for  $x=1$

However, in the complex plane, facing this example: ${z^4-1 \over z-i}$

I thought of going to polar coordinates:

${|z|^4e^{4i\theta}-1\over |z|e^{i\theta}-e^{i{\pi\over 2}}}$ which I multiply by $1$ using the conjugate of the denominator. However, this becomes quite messy.

Should I stick with Cartesian coordinates?

Using them, I tried again:

${(z^4-1)(z+i)\over (z-i)(z+i)} => {z^5+iz^4-z-i \over z^2 +1} |_{z=i} = { stuff \over -1+1}$ which again does not getus out.

Any passing advice would be greatly apreciated. (sorry for the computational nature of the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it's almost the same as the real case since
$$\frac{z^4-1}{z-i}=\frac{(z^3+iz^2-z-i)(z-i)}{z-i}=z^3+iz^2-z-i$$
for $z\ne i$.

Comment: which gives us -4i!!!   I see how it works! Relatively simple.